# Is the string '@LIBDIR@' somehow magic?

Tags: python, mercurial

For some reason I looked at [`/usr/bin/hg`](http://selenic.com/hg/file/1d7a36ff2615/hg) and saw what seemed like a strange bit of code:

```
libdir = '@LIBDIR@'

if libdir != '@' 'LIBDIR' '@':
    ...
```

The if statement looks like a tautology/contradiction as `'@LIBDIR@'` should always equal `'@' 'LIBDIR' '@'` in Python, so the code will never run.  Under what conditions does `'@LIBDIR@'` change into something else?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. It's probably meant for debugging or quick changing of the code.

Comment: @Veedrac Possibly, but it seems strange some debug code would be in a release version.

Comment: Perhaps so a tool can search for '@LIBDIR@' (sed, grep, etc.) and replace it if necessary.

Comment: @NickT: The placeholder is replaced by `setup.py` to the path where Mercurial is installed. The goal is to avoid letting `$PYTHONPATH` affect the libraries loaded by Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Mercurial *per se,* but to me `@LIBDIR@` is pretty clearly intended to be substituted with some other string by an automated search-and-replace, such as in a setup script. The `if` statement checks to see whether this in fact has been done: a search won't find `@LIBDIR@` in `'@' 'LIBDIR' '@'` so this is a way of comparing the variable's value to its *original placeholder value* without triggering the substitution of the placeholder in the `if` statement.

In other words, the `if` statement is asking, "if a library path has been specified at installation time, then validate it and add it to the Python module search path."

I'd personally put this information in a configuration file, since that would be easier for the user to edit and would be less likely to be clobbered by an update, but it looks like Mercurial is using the source code munging approach to configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The [commit message](http://selenic.com/hg/file/10da5a1f25dd/hg) says

> setup/hg: always load Mercurial from where it was installed.
>
> This provides two new features:
>
> - Mercurial may be installed into a non-standard location without   having to set PYTHONPATH.
> - Multiple installations can use Mercurial from different locations.

I guess you could email Dan for a more detailed answer